# Does JPA always pull entities into its cache?

Tags: java, jpa

We are using spring/JPA (not hibernate) to handle the deletion of all data in a table. However, the command would hit a java heap out of memory error. After some googling, it seems on delete that JPA pulls the entities first into memory before it deletes. My question is: Does JPA/spring always pull entity data into its cache? And how do we avoid out of memory errors when the returned data set is large? My current fix is to execute the DELETE command via a native query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some repository implementations might take a list of ids and load them, so that the remove operation can iterate over the loaded entities and relationships to ensure they are all cleared up, and that any events for affected entities are properly fired. Some objects have validations and other logic that should prevent some operations if they are in a certain state, state that cannot be checked unless the entities are loaded.

Try a bulk JPQL query for deletes if you don't want objects loaded. Similar to SQL but based on the entities and their relationships. Note that it does not respect the cascade operations set on the entity model mappings as it cannot know what is referenced and so doesn't try.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to resort to native SQL.

I don't think that `CrudRepository#deleteAll()` or `JpaRepository#deleteAllInBatch()` pulls anything into local cache, that would be seriously inefficient.

Comment: Agreed that it doesn't make sense! Although using the native SQL has fixed our issue for now. Regardless, I'm really curious to what folks thinks. Thanks for the input!

Comment: What implementation are you using? OpenJPA, EclipseLink?

Comment: We are using eclipselink